# Joining Elements in a List according to length - Python

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I am trying to design a parser for FASTA files (without using biopython) and am having problems in the following area:
I have a list of DNA sequences such as ['AAACCCGAU', 'AUUCCCCCCGGA', 'AACCCGGUU', 'AAACCCCUU'] etc.. named sequence_lines2.
My target program is:
If the element in the list has any multiple of 60 characters, join it to the next element. 
This way I can remove the line breaks in FASTA files. The code I have written looks like this:

```
for el in sequence_lines2:
    if len(el) == 60:
        sequence_lines3 = "".join(el)
```

How can I make this work? And how to achieve the multiples of 60?
Thanks in advance!

**----Edit----**
**If anyone's interesting in joining elements, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762695/joining-subsequent-list-elements-python)!.**

Comment: _This way I can remove the line breaks in FASTA files._ I think you could use more direct method to do so, without having to employ what seems to me to be a kind of a trick based on the length of DNA sequences present in a list that, I presume, you must build before, probably with **splitlines()* or something like that..... **re** module can be used to treat texts easily, for example detecting and removing newlines is very simple with regexes.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve here.  If your element lengths are 60, 120, 60, 28, 60, do you want to join the first four and keep the fifth separate, or join the first four and throw away the fifth, or join the first three and the fifth but throw away the fourth because its length isn't a multiple of 60 (which is what the accepted answer seems to do)?

Comment: Also: does the fasta format really specify that the line length should be a multiple of 60?  I thought the basic way of doing fasta parsing was just joining all the sequence lines until you find a header (i.e. a line starting with '>').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this one liner :

```
result = "".join([el for el in sequence_lines2 if not len(el) % 60])
```

The `len(el) % 60` computes the modulo of length with 60 and if the result is 0, this is a multiple of 60.

Comment: To expand on this: Cedric is using the % (modulus) operator. This tries to divide the left hand side of the operator by the right hand side and returns the remainder. When the remainder is 0, it is dividable by the right hand number, when there is a remainder it is not.

Comment: Thanks @Cedric! That works great with the = sign changed to ==. And many thanks @ikanobori for the explanation!

Comment: You can just do `if not len(el) % 60`, no extra parenthesis or comparison required.

Comment: @user851620 : yes, the second = was lost by my stupid fingers ;)