# Joining Subsequent List Elements - Python

Tags: python, merge

Is there a command to merge subsequent elements in a list - ie in a list ['AA', 'BB', 'C', 'D'] how would one merge the first two elements (or any others, depending on the code) in the list, leaving a list like ['AABB', 'C', 'D'] ? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following if you don't care about init list:

```
>>> a = ['AA', 'BB', 'C', 'D']
>>> a[0] += a.pop(1)
```

If you want to get new one and leave initList as is you can use something like this(note that this is just a sample):

```
a = ['AA', 'BB', 'C', 'D']
outList = a[:] # make a copy of list values
outList[0] += outputList.pop(1)
```

Or in some cases you can try to use something like this too:

```
from itertools import groupby

a = ['AA', 'BB', 'C', 'D']
res = [''.join((str(z) for z in y)) for x, y in groupby(a, key = lambda x: len(x) == 2)]
```

Comment: `outlist = a[:]`, then `outlist[0] += outlist.pop(1)` is better.

Comment: It always very annoying when people down-voting without saying a reason. Why you don't want to say something

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> a = ['AA', 'BB', 'C', 'D']
>>> a[0:2] = [''.join(a[0:2])]
>>> a
['AABB', 'C', 'D']
```

Comment: Only works for strings, slice assignment is a good trick though.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great way to do it. I think in my case I'll try @Artsiom's way first, but appreciate the effort!

Answer (score 1):

here is a python 3.x solution which uses iterators, and thus is compatible with any generator object (like `range` object...):

```
def merger(iterable, index=0, length=1):
    it = iter(iterable)
    for count in range(index):
        yield next(it)
    merged = next(it)
    for count in range(length-1):
        merged += next(it)
    yield merged
    for item in it:
        yield item
```